# Bootstrap 4 List-group item with arrow on right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and I need to create a list-group that has a title and an arrow on the right.

I'm get this a the moment:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h3 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Title 1
        </button>
      </h3>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Content here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Title 2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Content here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I need something more like this:

[Design screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGdDA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an arrow using `fontawesome` and make it `float:right`

```css
.accordion .card-header {
  padding: 0;
}

.accordion .card-header .btn-link{
  display: block;
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

.accordion .card-header .btn-link .fas {
  float:right;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.accordion .card-header .btn-link[aria-expanded="true"] .fas {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h3 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Title 1 <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
        </button>
      </h3>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Content here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Title 2 <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Content here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```